# Connection refused error installing quicklisp

Tags: sockets, common-lisp, quicklisp

On evaluating `(quicklisp-quickstart:install)` in SBCL I get(linux):

```
debugger invoked on a SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002978FF3}>:
  Socket error in "connect": ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-ERROR "connect")
```

and in CMUCL I get:

> Error in function CONNECT-TO-INET-SOCKET:    Error connecting socket
>   to [beta.quicklisp.org:80]: Connection refused    [Condition of type
>   SOCKET-ERROR]
>
> Restarts:   0: [ABORT] Return to Top-Level.
>
> Debug  (type H for help)
>
> (CONNECT-TO-INET-SOCKET "beta.quicklisp.org" 80 :STREAM :LOCAL-HOST
>   ...)

Comment: Are you able to access `beta.quicklisp.org` from a browser on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, and I "wgot" quicklisp without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if there is a proxy involved. Many system programs (like wget, web browsers, etc) will look at environment variables or other configurations to automatically use the proxy properly, but Quicklisp must be told about it explicitly.

You might see proxy settings in your environment variables.

If you know your proxy URL, you can set it during installation with the `:proxy` option to `install`.

Comment: That was it, however, proxy authentication is not yet supported so I get a http 407 :(

Comment: Sorry about that. Until Quicklisp is improved, there are some programs that locally connect dumb clients like Quicklisp through authenticating proxies. cntlm does that for NTLM-auth proxies, and I think there may be more for other proxies, too.

Comment: For future reference:One could set up a proxy to handle authentication for quicklisp, such as delegate or polipo.

Comment: Any suggestion in case proxy is off, and connection is refused if I try to update, but if I try to just install everything is fine?